# match a number (date) in a matrix - Matlab

Tags: search, matlab, date, date-manipulation

I have an interesting problem that involves taking the last `day` from a matrix and finding its `last month` day.  Eg, if the date today is Oct-10-2011, you try to search for Sep-10-2011 or the first day < Sep-10-2011 in the matrix.

Matrix has multiple IDs and last trading dates may not be the same. 
Vectorized solution is desired. Thanks!

```
mat = [
 1000 734507 11 ; 1000 734508 12 ; 1000 734509 13 ; 
 2001 734507 21 ; 2001 734508 22 ; 2001 734513 23 ; 2001 734516 25 ;
 1000 734536 14 ; 1000 734537 15 ; 1000 734538 16 ; 
 2001 734536 26 ; 2001 734537 27 ; 2001 734544 28 ; 2001 734545 29;2001 734546 30
];

% datestr(mat(:,2))
[~,m,~] = unique(mat(:,1), 'rows', 'last') ;
lastDay = mat(m,;) ;
```

Tried using `addtodate` to get last-month-date here but it fails (more than 1 row)

Once I get the last-dates for each ID, I need to get the exact_day_lastmonth.  After this, I need to get data on this day OR the day nearest to it (should be `< exact_day_lastmonth`).

Answer:

```
current_lastdays = [1000 734538 16 ;  2001 734546 30] ; % 4-Feb-2011, 12-Feb-2011
matching_lastmon = [1000 734507 11 ;  2001 734513 23] ; % 4-Jan-2011, 10-Jan-2011
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to risk rather large arrays with complicated indexing, I think a loop is the way to go.

```
mat = [ 1000 734507 11 ; 1000 734508 12 ; 1000 734509 13 ; 
        2001 734507 21 ; 2001 734508 22 ; 2001 734513 23 ; 2001 734516 25 ;
        1000 734536 14 ; 1000 734537 15 ; 1000 734538 16 ; 
2001 734536 26 ; 2001 734537 27 ; 2001 734544 28 ;2001 734545 29;2001 734546 30];

%# datestr(mat(:,2))
[~,m,~] = unique(mat(:,1), 'rows', 'last') ;
lastDay = mat(m,;) ;

matching_lastmon = lastDay; %# initialize matching_lastmon
oneMonthBefore = datenum(bsxfun(@minus,datevec(lastDay(:,2)),[0,1,0,0,0,0]));

for iDay = 1:size(lastDay,1)
    %# the following assumes that the array `mat` is sorted within each ID (or globally sorted by date)

    idx = find(mat(:,1)==lastDay(iDay,1) & mat(:,2) <= oneMothBefore(iDay),1,'last')

    if isempty(idx)
        matching_lastmon(iDay,2:3) = NaN;
    else
        matching_lastmon(iDay,:) = mat(idx,:);
    end


end
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas.  Im trying to use a different approach now.  Im afraid that running a for-loop on a very big matrix (>1m rows) can take a lot of time.  I did get a close answer - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/17921-match-a-number-date-in-a-matrix-matlab but it fails when a matching entry is not found last month.

Comment: @Jonas... my understanding was `arrayfun` runs much faster than a for-loop.  I can do with creating a very large array (putting dummy rows with nan values).  I would then replace nan with values above that come from same ID.  I have posted a new Q for that.  Thanks Jonas!

Comment: @Maddy: I have incorporated the good idea for the vectorized calculated look-up of the last month's date (use the profiler to check whether it's indeed faster than using `addtodate`!), and I have added a check for when the matching entry is not found.

Comment: @Maddy: Maybe in a more recent version of Matlab they multi-thread arrayfun, so it may be getting you some speed gains.